# Connect To VSFTP using Android

Tags: android, apache, ftp

hello I am trying to connect from a android to a vsftp server
the company that hosts the server gave me the username and password and @ip.

I made an example to connect me and download a file, but I have problem to login, the connection is made but after there is no  no answer, I use a virtual android device to test my example exemple. the problem is in the method mftp.login it returns false .

this is my class that connect to the server

```
private class connection extends AsyncTask{

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            boolean retour = ftpConnect( "x.y.z.w",  "username", "password",  21);
            return retour;
        }

        public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,String password, int port){
              try {

                    mFTPClient = new FTPClient();

                    try {

                         mFTPClient.connect(host, 21);

                            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {

                                /* Set File Transfer Mode
                                *
                                * To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct
                                * transfer mode, such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE,
                                * EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE .etc. Here, I use BINARY_FILE_TYPE
                                * for transferring text, image, and compressed files.
                                */

                                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                                boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
                                Log.i("cause", "this is the status of loging "+status);
                                FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/doc.pdf");
                                mFTPClient.retrieveFile("x.y.z.w/mydirectory/doc.pdf", desFileStream);
                                return status;
                           }

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e(username,"no idea");
                    }


                  } catch(Exception e) {
                      Log.e(username,"no idea 2 ");
                     }    

             return false;
        }
```

i'm sure i don't have eror in my code , 
I tried to connect from a web page, but I can not, I tried with dos  command   but there's no response, they told me that i can just connect from an android device.

I searched  for vsftp and I found that it is secured.
 1* my questions is that can i connect from a virtual device?
 2*  which configuration they did to not allow for the connection from web page or virtual device?

I already tried with filezilla but it gave  530 login incorect

3* could you tell me what causes that do not allow me to  login to the server . the problem comes from  my program or from the server.

4* i use apache library for connecting to the server ftp , it's too  good for vsftp ?

and thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you can acces from a web/filezilla and they allow to acces from out of their local network, sure yes.
2. Dont know but if they dont allow external connections you cant. they probably do it for security.
3. As you explain, of the server.
4. I think that yes.

Conclusion: If they do not allow external connections you can't connect for example here is a guy that mount this server and he should enable connections for his own red.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068591

Comment: thank you tato469.  the problem is i can connect but i can't logging

Comment: that is strange, try to post here: http://serverfault.com/ they might helps you :) But I think that is the configuration of the server, do you have acces to this configuration?

Comment: no the server is hostes in other company,  i have doubt if i must use a library that can comunicate with vsftpd, are you sure that can i use ftp library rather than vsftp ??

Comment: FTP is a protocol and vsftp is a FTP server software. I think that yes but ask in the other forum they will sure know what is happening. luck! :)

Comment: hy i have posted their but they said to me that there is not the good forum for programming question, and they sais that i must put here my question , i didn't find any solution for my problem , and for new information :  i can to connect just to my folder in the server , what must i add in y code to do that

Comment: they didnt reply your questions? (4 questions) I think that they should be know it :/ you can connect away of their local net? or you can connect only to your folder when you are connected in local?

Comment: i can connect to the server but i can't login with my username and my password  the mftclient.login return false , i don't know why.    yes the company that host server said that i can connect just to my folder in the server. i can do anyting if  the login method return false

Comment: Sorry dude I think that I can't help you more, I don't have any idea what is wrong.

Comment: thank you tato469 for your answers, i solved problem it was because the ftp server banned device from external network, i connected from internal network.

Comment: Welcome, I thought that was the problem.